# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'selfClosingTags' and 'isHTML'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got a TypeError while making a learing test program.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

newurl = 'http://susumr.cc/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(newurl,'lxml')
print(soup.text)
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'selfClosingTags' and 'isHTML'
```

Third party library I also installed, I do not know how this is, and confused for several days

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass html string to `BeautifulSoup` constructor, not url.

```
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

newurl = 'http://susumr.cc/'
content = urllib.urlopen(newurl).read()  # Retrive url content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')  # pass the content to `BeautifulSoup` constructor
print(soup.text)
```